# Problemas com React-Native

Tags: android, react-native

Olá, eu estava instalando o react-native no meu PC, quando fui dar "npx react-native run-android" dentro da pasta do projeto, ele da um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta criar um projeto do Desktop e não na System32 e veja se essa pasta existe, o erro é que o diretório não existe, tenta criar um novo projeto, ctrlC e ctrlV no que você já criou  e baixa as dependências novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você realizou a importação correta das Libs ?

Da um:

npm install

Nessa pasta e tante novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Vi que você está instalando seu projeto na pasta:

`C:\windows\system32`

Não é recomendável instalar programas ou fazer alterações nessa pasta específica, sugiro que você inicie seu projeto em diretórios do seu usuário. Por exemplo:

`C:\users\erickson\Documents`

Outro motivo do comando não estar funcionando é pelo fato da pasta ser dos arquivos de sistemas e requerer autorização especial de Administrador.